# How to make conditional build task on android build gradle

Tags: android, gradle

In android, we would like to make one app build with different application id depends on the pre-installed app package.
So it contains flavor in the build gradle with different applicationId set.

But we don't want all these flavors been build, we just want to only build the one based on pre-installed app package name to save sometime on build server.

If used

```
task prepareA（dependsOn:['assembleADebug']){}

task prepareB（dependsOn:['assembleBDebug']){}

task prepareTest(dependsOn:['prepareA', 'prepareB']) {}
```

Then when called `prepareTest`, both `prepareA` and `prepareB` would be executed with both `assembleADebug` and `assembleBDebug` executed.

I only want to build either `prepareA` or `prepareB` be executed based on one condition check (if ...).

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found after some hours invesigation, it is that we can use afterEvaluate method, which would execute before dependsOn is running.

Remove the predefined dependsOn the the prepareA and prepareＢ.

```
Then

afterEvaluate {
    if (isPackageInstalled(packageName)) {             
        tasks.findByName("prepareTest").dependsOn("prepareA")
    } else {
        tasks.findByName("prepareTest").dependsOn("prepareB")
    }
}
```